# Read and write using pipes

Tags: c, process, pipe, parent-child

I have a program with 2 child processes which has to do the following:

- use the parent to read data from a file 'data.txt' and write in a pipe
- use a child to read the data from the pipe and filter the lowercase letters
- use another child to write the filtered letters in a new file, each on a new line

I tried to do it and it works... kinda. The problem is, it writes the filtered letters in the desired file, but the program does not stop. What am I doing wrong?

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    int parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[2], child1Child2FileDescriptors[2];
    
    void parentProcess()
    {
        close(child1Child2FileDescriptors[0]);
        close(child1Child2FileDescriptors[1]);
        close(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[0]);
    
        int fileDescriptor = open("data.txt", O_RDONLY);
        char buffer[8];
        int store;
        while ((store = read(fileDescriptor, buffer, 8)))
        {
            write(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[1], buffer, store);
        }
        close(fileDescriptor);
    
        close(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[1]);
    }
    
    void child1Process()
    {
        close(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[1]);
        close(child1Child2FileDescriptors[0]);
    
        char buffer[8];
        int store, count = 0;
        while ((store = read(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[0], buffer, 8)))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < store; i++)
            {
                if (buffer[i] >= 'a' && buffer[i] <= 'z')
                {
                    count++;
                    write(child1Child2FileDescriptors[1], &buffer[i], sizeof(buffer[i]));
                }
            }
        }
        printf("CHILD 1 FINISHED FILTERING\n");
    
        close(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[0]);
        close(child1Child2FileDescriptors[1]);
    
        exit(count);
    }
    
    void child2Process()
    {
        close(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[0]);
        close(child1Child2FileDescriptors[1]);
    
        mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH;
        char *fileName = "stat.txt";
        int newFileDescriptor = creat(fileName, mode);
        char buffer;
        int store;
        while ((store = read(child1Child2FileDescriptors[0], &buffer, 1)))
        {
            write(newFileDescriptor, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            write(newFileDescriptor, "\n", 1);
        }
        close(newFileDescriptor);
    
        printf("CHILD 2 FINISHED WRITING'\n");
    
        close(child1Child2FileDescriptors[0]);
        close(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[1]);
    
        exit(444);
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
        if (pipe(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors) < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR CREATING PIPE\n");
            exit(-100);
        }
    
        if (pipe(child1Child2FileDescriptors) < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR CREATING PIPE\n");
            exit(-101);
        }
    
        pid_t child1PID = fork();
        if (child1PID < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR CREATING CHILD\n");
            exit(-200);
        }
        if (!child1PID)
        {
            child1Process();
        }
    
        pid_t child2PID = fork();
        if (child2PID < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR CREATING CHILD\n");
            exit(-201);
        }
        if (!child2PID)
        {
            child2Process();
        }
    
        parentProcess();
        int status1, status2;
        waitpid(child1PID, &status1, 0);
        waitpid(child2PID, &status2, 0);
        printf("CHILD 1 TERMINATED WITH EXIT STATUS: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status1));
        printf("CHILD 2 TERMINATED WITH EXIT STATUS: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status2));
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read loop in child1process will never terminate, because child2 still has the write side of that pipe open.  You need to execute:

```
close(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[1]);
```

before you enter the read loop. The general rule is that if a process isn't going to use a file descriptor, it should close it immediately.

Comment: I think that was the problem. I left the writing part of that pipe opened even tho I was not using it.

Answer (score -1):

your  `while ((store = read(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[0], buffer, 8)))` loop is never gonna end.

The parent needs to say to the child that there is no more data coming and it shall not do another read.
You can do this by sending a special byte.

Example :

in the parent:

```
char endByte = 0x1;
write(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[1], &endByte, 1);
//then close
```

in the while loop of the child :

```
if(buffer[i] ==  0x1){
    printf("CHILD 1 FINISHED FILTERING\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    close(parentChildpipeFileDescriptors[0]);
    close(child1Child2FileDescriptors[1]);

    exit(count);
};
```

Comment: You do not need to write a special byte.  It is sufficient to close the file descriptor.  If the child does not get EOF on the next read, it is because some other process still has the write end of the pipe open.

Comment: This works, but as @WilliamPursell said, I do not think it's really the right way to do it.